# Simplest way to pass @Published data to a Textfield()?

Tags: swiftui, combine

**Scenario:**
I'm using an Observable Class to acquire data from the network. 
In this case some elementary weather data.

**Problem:**

I don't know how to display this data in the calling View.

For the time-being, I merely am trying to populate a Textfield (and worry about more-eleborate layout later).

I get the following:

> .../StandardWeatherView.swift:22:13: Cannot invoke initializer for
>   type 'TextField<_>' with an argument list of type '(Text, text:
>   Sample?)'

Here's is my calling View which is the receiver of @ObservedObject data:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StandardWeatherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
    @ObservedObject var standardWeatherReportLoader = StandardWeatherReportLoader()

    init() {
        self.standardWeatherReportLoader.doStandard()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("FernGreen").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            TextField(Text("Weather Data"), text: standardWeatherReportLoader.weatherReport)
        }
    }
}

struct StandardWeatherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StandardWeatherView()
    }
}
```

Here's the publisher, acquiring data:

```
import Foundation

class StandardWeatherReportLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var networkMessage: String?
    @Published var hasAlert = false
    @Published var weatherReport: Sample?
    @Published var hasReport = false

    func doStandard() {
        let url = EndPoint.weather.path()
        var request = URLRequest(url: EndPoint.weather.path()!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data: Data?, _: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard error == nil else {
                    self.networkMessage = error?.localizedDescription
                    self.hasAlert = true
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let result = try decoder.decode(Sample.self, from: data!)
                    self.weatherReport = result
                    self.hasReport = true
                    print("\n Standard Weather ----------------")
                    print(#function, "line: ", #line, "Result: ",result)
                    print("\n")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

What's the simplest way of passing a string of data to the View via @Published var?

Log:

> Standard Weather ---------------- doStandard() line:  38 Result: 
>   Sample(coord: DataTaskPubTab.Coord(lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51), weather:
>   [DataTaskPubTab.Weather(id: 300, main: "Drizzle", description: "light
>   intensity drizzle")], base: "stations", main:
>   DataTaskPubTab.Main(temp: 280.32, pressure: 1012, humidity: 81,
>   tempMin: 279.15, tempMax: 281.15), visibility: 10000, wind:
>   DataTaskPubTab.Wind(speed: 4.1, deg: 80), clouds:
>   DataTaskPubTab.Clouds(all: 90), dt: 1485789600.0, id: 2643743, name:
>   "London")

But I'm getting nil at the TextField:

> (lldb) po standardWeatherReportLoader.weatherReport  nil

Comment: It is not clear your expectation... `TextField.text` requires `Binding<String>` but you try to pass there `Sample` which is custom type.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set a binding within your body to track whenever the TextField has updated. From within this binding, you can then edit your Published variable as you wish:

```
@ObservedObject var reportLoader = StandardWeatherReportLoader()

var body: some View {

        // Binding to detect when TextField changes
        let textBinding = Binding<String>(get: {
            self.reportLoader.networkMessage
        }, set: {
            self.reportLoader.networkMessage = $0
        })

        // Return view containing the text field
        return VStack {

                TextField("Enter the Network Message", text: textBinding)
        }
}
```

Edit: Also in your original post, you were passing an object of optional type Sample into the TextField which was expecting a binding String type which could cause some issues.

Comment: Yah, I noticed that.   Passing an actual string component of the Sample DOES work.   So either I handle the entire object or in string-piecemeal bits.  But I prefer working with such objects.  I'll study your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to GET info from reportLoader; not setting its value from the View.  It appears that it's easier to disseminate info from within reportLoader and send bits back to the view in hashable entities like strings vs bindable objects.